# Overwrite branches while keeping the branch commits

Tags: git

My team and i worked on 6 Branches.

Yesterday we merged all Branches into one.

Today we did some bugfixing.
We now want to continue on our branches.

But before, everyone needs the merged code.

We dont want to create new branches but would like to copy the master into these six branches.

What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to add the bugfix to all the branches? meaning add master to all the branches?

Comment: we had the master branch, created six branches (Developing on different features) and merged all 6 in the master. Now we want to continue working on the six branches with the merged code

Comment: thank you, i'm comming back when we were successfull!

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you want to create new branches? [Git branches are lightweight](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is), which means they are just references pointing to a commit. Creating a new branch should be just a matter of starting your work with a reference that points to the same commit that `master` does:

1. Switch to `master`:

   `git checkout master`
2. Make sure `master` is up-to-date:

   `git pull --ff-only`
3. Create a new branch:

   `git checkout -b <new-branch-name>`

If instead of creating new branches, you would still prefer to work on the same branch as before, you can always make that branch point to the latest `master`:

1. Switch to the existing branch:

   `git checkout <existing-branch-name>`
2. Make the current branch point to the same commit as `master`:

   `git merge --ff-only master`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the `hotfix` code from master to all the other branches you can simply use `cherry-pick`.

#### `cherry-pick`

choose which commits (from any branch or even can be loose commit) pick this commit and place it in my current branch, in other words - take any commit from anywhere in the repository add bring it to my branch

---

#### `merge`

If you simply want to merge the code added to the master branch to your branches each developer can simply do the following:

```
# Update the local repo with the code from master
git fetch --all --prune

# merge master into the development branch
git checkout <my branch>
git pull origin master

# now all the changes from master are on your branch.
#verify that you have the changes:
git log --oneline --graph --decorate
```